Cambiar fecha BlazorApp Weather
Estoy intentado modificar el código del módulo Weather que es la plantilla que te dá al crear un proyecto Blazor en Visual Studio. Le añadí un input de fecha para que al seleccionar una me muestre la previsión de los siguientes 7 días a la fecha elegida(lo genera aleatoriamente) pero no logro que se actualice con otra fecha. Ya me cansé de preguntarle a chatGPT.
Hola, Estoy intentado modificar el código del módulo Weather que es la plantilla que te dá al crear un proyecto Blazor en Visual Studio. Le añadí un input de fecha para que al seleccionar una me muestre la previsión de los siguientes 7 días a la fecha elegida(lo genera aleatoriamente) pero no logro que se actualice con otra fecha. Ya me cansé de preguntarle a chatGPT.
@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>Este componente muestra datos.</p>

<div>
    <label for="selectedDate">Selecciona una fecha:</label>
    <InputDate id="selectedDate" @bind-Value="selectedDate" @onchange="LoadForecasts" />
</div>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Cargando...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Resumen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Now;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitializedAsync called");
        await LoadForecasts();
    }

    private async Task LoadForecasts(ChangeEventArgs? e = null)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            selectedDate = DateTime.Parse(e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"LoadForecasts called with selectedDate: {selectedDate}");

        // Simula la carga asincrónica para demostrar el streaming rendering
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(selectedDate);
        var summaries = new[] { "Helado", "Fresco", "Fresco", "Agradable", "Moderado", "Cálido", "Agradable", "Caluroso", "Bochornoso", "Abrasador" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index).ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();

        // Forzar el re-renderizado
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}

Lo he intentado añadiendo un botón pero tampoco lo consigo.


Al cambiar la fecha no se actualiza.

Lo que yo creo que pasa es que Blazor utiliza el evento onchange para hacer el Binding, entonces no puedes tener un @bind-Value y un @onchange al mismo tiempo.
Soluciones hay muchas, aquí unas cuantas:
1) Utilizar oninput
<InputDate id="selectedDate" @bind-Value="selectedDate" @oninput="LoadForecasts" />

2) No bindear el valor
El binding en Blazor es bidireccional, pero tu solo utilizas una dirección (la propiedad escribe al input), por lo que en tu caso puedes convertirlo a unidireccional
<input type="date" id="selectedDate" value="@selectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" @onchange="LoadForecasts" />

3) Binding bidireccional
Como te decía, el binding en Blazor es bidireccional (por eso no se utiliza el onchange). Los cambios los debes detectar en la propiedad
<InputDate id="selectedDate" @bind-Value="selectedDate"  />

@code{
    private DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime selectedDate{
        get => _selectedDate;
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedDate)
            {
                LoadForecasts();
            }
        }
    }
    
}


Gracias por responder. Al final faltaba poner esta línea:
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer
Llegué a esa conclusión gracias al comentario de un usuario en un video de dotnet que lo decía. Sin eso parece ser que no funciona nada.

@leokode eso no tiene nada que ver. El renderMode configura quien renderiza el código (el servidor o el cliente). En cambio, un evento se produce cuando la página ya ha sido renderizada y presentada al cliente. Igualmente comprobé lo que señalas y no funciona. La imposibilidad de tener un bind junto con el onchange es algo que está desde la primera versión y pasa por un tema de diseño

@Yussef. Sí esa parte lo entiendo y es verdad no funciona un bind con un onchange , pero lo del renderMode es así como te digo y por lo poco que entendí en la documentación de ASP.NET.
Lo estoy haciendo desde el lado del server, te muestro el código como me quedó y es el que funciona con @rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer:
@page "/weather"
@using BlazorApp.Services
@inject CsvService CsvService
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>Este componente muestra datos.</p>

<p>Nombre: @Name</p>

<div>
    <label for="nameInput">Ingrese su nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" @bind="Name" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="selectedDate">Selecciona una fecha:</label>
    <input type="date" id="selectedDate" @bind="selectedDate" />
    <input type="number" id="numberOfDays" @bind="numberOfDays" min="1" max="30" />
    <button @onclick="LoadForecasts">Cargar Previsiones</button>
    @if (forecasts != null)
    {
        <button @onclick="DownloadCsv">Descargar CSV</button>
    }
</div>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Cargando...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Resumen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private DateOnly selectedDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
    private int numberOfDays = 7;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "John Doe";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await LoadForecasts();
    }

    private async Task LoadForecasts()
    {
        // Simula la carga asincrónica para demostrar el streaming rendering
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var summaries = new[] { "Helado", "Fresco", "Fresco", "Agradable", "Moderado", "Cálido", "Agradable", "Caluroso", "Bochornoso", "Abrasador" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = selectedDate.AddDays(index).ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();

        // Forzar el re-renderizado
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task DownloadCsv()
    {
        if (forecasts == null) return;

        var csvData = CsvService.GenerateCsv(forecasts);
        var fileName = $"WeatherForecasts_{selectedDate.ToShortDateString()}.csv";

        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(csvData);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $"var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = 'data:text/csv;base64,{base64}'; a.download = '{fileName}'; a.click();");
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}

Clase CsvService (Añade un botón para descargar como csv)
namespace BlazorApp.Services
{
    using System.Text;

    public class CsvService
    {
        public byte[] GenerateCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            var csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Escribir encabezados
            csvBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", properties.Select(p => p.Name)));

            // Escribir filas
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
                csvBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", values));
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvBuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
}

Es lo que te digo porque lo he comprobado, sin la directiva @rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer no funcionan los eventos de los botones para nada
